# ExpressionEngine's tag integration issue

Tags: html, plugins, content-management-system, expressionengine

I'm fairly new to expression engine so forgive me if this question comes across pretty obvious I have a slight problem with integrating exp:resso store tag in my temple, for some reason all 
the code i apply under exp:resso's {store} tag doesn't appear on my broswer. The code below demonstrates how i have structured my EE tags, please correct me if i'm wrong...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="6" paginate="bottom"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="1" return="cart"}
    <ul class="inventory">
        <li class="item2"> {p_productimage}<a href="#"><img class="itemImg" alt="" src="{p_productimage_image}"/></a>{/p_productimage}
        <div class="product-fam1">
            <h3>{p_title}</h3>
            <a class="viewItem" href="#"><img src="iamnatesmithen.com/fluotics/css/images/viewItem.jpg";</a>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

ExpressionEngine test site: http://www.iamnatesmithen.com/ExpressionEngine2/index.php/inventory

Current static site: http://iamnatesmithen.com/fluotics/products.html

Comment: {exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="6" paginate="bottom"}
 {exp:store:product entry_id="1" return="cart"}<ul class="inventory"> 
  <li class="item2"> {p_productimage}<a href="#"><img class="itemImg" alt="" src="{p_productimage_image}"/></a>{/p_productimage} <div class="product-fam1"><h3>{p_title}</h3><a class="viewItem" href="#"><img src="http://www.iamnatesmithen.com/fluotics/css/images/viewItem.jpg" </a></div>
        </li>
        </ul>
   {/exp:store:product}
        {/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: Link to my static site http://iamnatesmithen.com/fluotics/products.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not passing the product's entry id to {exp:store:product} correctly. Have you tried this? Note {exp:store:product entry_id="**{entry_id}**"...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="6" paginate="bottom"}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" return="cart"}
     <!-- snip -->
    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```